# What does this mean in jquery $('#id', javascript_object);

Tags: jquery

what does this `$('#id', javascript_object);` mean in jquery . I know that we can pass a context in the second parameter to the selector . But what happens when the second parameter is a javascript object .

Thanks in advance for the help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is the [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). It restricts searching to a specific document object or the children of a certain DOM element.

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, if within a callback function we wish to do a search for an element, we can restrict that search:
>
> ```
> $('div.foo').click(function() {
>   $('span', this).addClass('bar');
> });
> ```
>
> Since we've restricted the span selector to the context of this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.

In the example you show, you would be searching for the element with the ID `id` among the children of `javascript_object`.

Comment: `// HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))} else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {return (context || rootjQuery).find( selector );`

jQuery will call `(context).find(selector)` when parsing that pattern. So in general, it's recommendable to directly use the `.find()` notation.

Comment: But that means that it will fail if it is an arbitrary JavaScript object, doesn't it? I think the OP already knows what it is about this context.