# jQuery : $('element', something)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does this mean in jquery $('#id', javascript_object);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262974/what-does-this-mean-in-jquery-id-javascript-object)
>   [What does $(''class for the same element', element) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479300/what-does-class-for-the-same-element-element-mean)
>   [What does the second argument to $() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979097/what-does-the-second-argument-to-mean)

Anyone know what are:

```
$('element', $$).function(){...};
```

([seen here](http://jsbin.com/ohiyo/21/edit#javascript,html))

And

```
$('element', this).function(){...};
```

([seen here](http://blog.jaysalvat.com/article/creez-une-arborescence-de-fichiers-en-jquery-6))

?

Comment: Which information in addition to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) do you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean in jquery $('#id', javascript_object);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262974/what-does-this-mean-in-jquery-id-javascript-object) and [What does $(''class for the same element', element) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479300/what-does-class-for-the-same-element-element-mean) and [What does the second argument to $() mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979097/what-does-the-second-argument-to-mean).

Comment: From the doc:  "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')."

Comment: @FelixKling: they were not proposed in the suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the second argument to $() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979097/what-does-the-second-argument-to-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.pblabel', this).text(newVal + '%');
```

Is the same thing as

```
$(this).find('.pblabel').text(newVal + '%');
```

In fact, that is the way it is rewritten and run internally.  It is called the "context selector".

From the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L164):

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))
} else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {
    return ( context || rootjQuery ).find( selector );

// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It uses `this` or `$$` as the context, i.e. all elements returned must be its descendants. The default is `document`.

Comment: @GG. No, it could be any variable. `$` are valid in variable and function names (hence jQuery's main `$` function).